# how to uncheck already checked input

Tags: javascript, jquery

For every event I can book users on it. But in case that there are no free places to book, i show user an error message. Now I would like to also disable the checkbox he selected (some event).

When selected my input looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

Now in JS. If there is this event already booked and no free places i show this:

```
$('.jtable tr.jtable-data-row td.jtable-selecting-column input:checkbox').click(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var closestTr = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-record-key');
        $.ajax({
             url: 'Actions.php?action=resp',
             type: 'post',
             data: '&id='+closestTr,
             success: function(output) 
               var $res = output.substring(11, 14); 
               if( $res == 'NOK' ){
                  $(this).prop('checked', false);
                  alert('Already booked.'); 
                       }
             }, error: function()
               alert('something went wrong');
             }
       });
} 

});
```

From some reason I cant get it unchecked, i already tried 10 things and no results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your `$(this)` is pointing to the actual checkbox input you're trying to uncheck? Because this JS syntax should work properly

Comment: It's hard to say exactly without seeing more code.

Comment: updated with main parts

Comment: Just for fun - a simplified JS fiddle showing that your code works - http://jsfiddle.net/K9eQr/. You need to provide more information, because the code works as given.

Comment: Also... what is `output`? Are you sure it's the value you expect?

Comment: lol i found my error now, got it working

Comment: @enigmaticus, please post your answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved it, after

```
var closestTr = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-record-key');
var th=$(this);
```

And than in AJAX success:

```
if( $res == 'NOK' ){
    th.prop('checked', false);
    alert('Already booked.'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1.) `$(this).prop('checked', '');`

2.) `$(this).attr('checked', '');`

I would prefer `change` event rather than `click`.

Comment: neither 1 or 2 are correct. you must either remove `attr('checked')` completely or set `prop('checked')` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

you are not selecting checkbox properly

```
$('.jtable tr.jtable-data-row').on("click", "td.jtable-selecting-column input:checkbox ",function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       var $res = output.substring(11, 14); 
       if( $res == 'NOK' ){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
            alert('Already booked.'); 
       }
  }
});
```

Comment: Code is not enough of an answer. Let the OP know what you changed.

Comment: You changed `.click` to `.on('click'`. How does that fix the `checkbox` selector?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(this).prop('checked', false);

    or 

$(this).attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: How is your answer different from @Harsh Chiki?

Comment: prop is right as checked is property and not attribute